# Tired of This Kind of Riddle Already?

Tags: riddle

My prefix is commonly found in games where players get to upgrade their character's stats

My infix is always full of green colors

My suffix is a place where people can board on trains

My whole consists of 13 letters

Guess the word!

Comment: *Answering the title*: nope.

Comment: Lol. I was actually afraid of posting too much questions @user477343

Comment: Hahah, no need. You can post as many puzzles/answers as you like! It is highly encouraged that this site has an active community. Besides, many users like these kinds of puzzles (including myself), hence the upvotes :)

Comment: Ok. Will do so. I just hope that there is no time limit (40 min) to post questions :)

Comment: You can post whenever you feel like it; the site does not wish to be of any inconvenience :)

Comment: Looking at [your most recent riley-riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69443/cant-get-enough-of-riley-riddles), could the third line refer to Rot13(ntr)?

Comment: You just hit the nail in the head. Why don't you try answering it? @user477343

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> deforestation

My prefix is commonly found in games where players get to upgrade their character's stats

> DEF

My infix is always full of green colors

> Forest

My suffix is a place where people can board on trains

> Station

My whole consists of 13 letters

Comment: Correct! Will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure since the infix clue doesn't entirely match, but

> deforestation? Def is a stat in RPGs, ore can contain green crystals (but also other colors, so that is kind of iffy), and trains are boarded from stations.

Comment: Nice! But you got the infix part wrong

Comment: Just posted my answer a few seconds too late :)

Comment: +1 For getting 2 parts correct, though :)