# Can't Get Enough of Riley Riddles

Tags: riddle

My prefix is an abbreviation of a 3 word phrase

My infix is what robbers put on their victims

My suffix is what no human being in this world can stop

My whole consists of just 6 letters

What is the word?

Extra Hint for the Prefix Part (as no one seems to get it) :

> It is what reporters do before they present the news

Comment: I think the hint will make the answer a bit too obvious @user477343

Comment: I believe I might have the word, but the prefix is getting me. But if you choose not to put the hint, it is fine :)

Comment: Just updated the hint. Hopefully this can help solve the question @user477343

Comment: In my country, reporters either say "Breaking news" or they just start with bad news.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is-

> Engage

Prefix-

> Eng , Electronic News Gathering, suggested by @u_ndefined

Infix-

> gag, robbers put gag on their victims

Suffix-

> age, no one can stop from aging, (unless they are vampires or superheroes, lol)

last hint-

> engage also means participation

Comment: That's exactly what I thought :D

Comment: Missing the prefix part. Will accept after you correct it.

Comment: still trying to figure out the prefix, will update as soon as i get it.

Comment: You can say that but there is another one that is more common in my country. BTW, (???)lish is not a 3 word phrase lol @u_ndefined

Comment: @KevinL I was thinking that the three word phrase might be something along the lines of "expect no good" or "expect nothing greater (more)". But when I go [here](https://www.brainz.org/100-best-3-word-phrases/), I can't seem to find one phrase starting with E.

Comment: Still wrong @ShahriarMahmudSajid

Comment: Nope @u_ndefined

Comment: @user477343 Nope that is so far from the real phrase. Gotta go AFK for a while

Comment: Prefix: Rot13(Ryrpgebavp Arjf Trgurevat)

Comment: You got it @u_ndefined

Comment: @KevinL the only three word phrases I know of that starts with E is "Enough is enough" or "Easy as pie". I think there was a fairy tale called the "Emperor's New Clothes" but that doesn't cut it. I might answer one of your riley riddles next time; i.e., if you make some more :)

Comment: Lol. I guess the prefix wasn't so common after all @user477343

Comment: you can try mine as well, made one today

Comment: Will check it out later @ShahriarMahmudSajid